# What is the right way of using es6 Map and Set in functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

Map and Set obviously were built for mutations, most methods mutate, with exceptions like `has` which doesn't change collection.

So we have to make a copy and mutate it like:

```
// Instead of: map.set(4, 'four');
const map2 = new Map(map).set(4, 'four');

// Instead of: map.delete(1);
const map3 = new Map(map).delete(1);

// Instead of: map.clear();
const map4 = new Map() 
/* Should we create a variable called emptyMap
   and reuse it for cases where we need an empty Map
   because all operations would create a copy anyway? */
```

Is this the right way to do things?

Maybe writing a small library of functions to work with Map and Set is a  better option (maybe there is one already?).

Alternatively have seen examples like:

```
// Instead of: map.set(4, 'four');
const map2 = new Map([...map, [4, 'four']]);

// Instead of: map.delete(1);
const map3 = new Map([...map].filter(([key]) => key !== 1));

// Instead of: map.clear();
const map4 = new Map();
```

I dislike first because it creates two arrays, second one looks terrible since filter would have to go over each element, what is even the point to use Map instead of array then?

Comment: This isn’t really about functional programming, but about immutability.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to title it, immutably updating Map and Set? Or Immutability: Map and Set?

Comment: And functional programming would require immutability.

Comment: Your title/tag is just right. immutability is a core concept of FP.

Comment: You should use a data type according to its design. The important thing is to keep the scope as small as possible where mutations occur and to aggregate them within this scope. Ideally, inside a function. If you cannot avoid mutations from leaking into the global scope you can create a copy before passing it to the code causing the leakage. Coyping a reference value once is an acceptable trade-off.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt It is kind of hard to understand for me, can you provide more details or examples?

Comment: "*filter would have to go over each element, what is even the point to use Map instead of array then?*" - well `new Map(map)` or `new Map([...map])` also go over each element, you just don't see it as good in the code. Copying a `Map` is inefficient, don't do it if you care. Use [purely functional data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_data_structure) instead in functional programming.

Comment: @Bergi yes it would, but that is a required step we can't avoid it, the filter one we can actually. JS doesn't have such data structures, they would have to be implemented on top of what we have, there is immutable js but for my case where I have small depth and not big size of collections it would be too much overhead probably.

Comment: @link2name Not sure what you mean by "avoid the `filter` step"? And yes, using JS data structures (builtin or not) in a functional way incurs overhead, this is unfortunate but true.

Comment: Well one code uses copy and `delete` method that doesn't have to go over each element, while the filter code does copy and also has to use filter which would go over each element. So we can avoid filter and use delete method which is much better.

Comment: @link2name Copying does have to go over each element anyway. Whether you filter while copying, preventing the to-be-removed element from being added to the new map in the first place, or whether you `.delete()` it afterwards, doesn't make that much of a difference - both are of linear complexity. I'd actually prefer the former (`filter`) as cleaner. Not sure how you measure "better".

Comment: Less times to go over same collection is better.

Comment: Then use [iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) as `new Map(map.entries().filter(([key]) => key !== 1));` which goes over the collection only once as well.

Comment: I don't see how is that better, it still has to go over whole collection versus just deleting a key.

Comment: `new Map(map)` also has to go over the whole `map` collection, there's no difference. Copying the map is not a constant-time operation, the `Map` constructor is iterating the passed argument.

Comment: You think that if we write  `new Map(map.entries().filter(([key]) => key !== 1));` it will merge copy and filter into one iteration?

Comment: Yes, that's what filtering an iterator does

Comment: This is strange, where can I read about this?

Comment: I've posted [the link](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) above

Comment: That is a very big document, where exactly is it?

Comment: Do you mean the fact that it instead of filtering will return an iterator so it kind of didn't go over collection yet?

Comment: Ok I understand that it will iterate only when we actually call new Map(), but when it does it would have to go over each element and test its equality right?

Comment: It seems like delete method basically does what filter does (also tests all elements). So yeah I guess there is no difference or it is small. Somewhy I expected that it would not be affected by collection size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249028/discussion-between-link2name-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding mutations is about relaxing the order constraint in your code. Since single threaded JS' concurrency model is based on an event loop, you can experience race conditions only in asynchronous code but order still matters:

```
const xs = [1,2,3], ys = [1,2,3];

xs.push(4);
xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 10
ys.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 6
ys.push(4);
```

The same impure computations in different orders yield different results without the interpreter complaining. Besides, mutations are implicit, that is, they are hard to spot/track.

But data types designed with mutation in mind should still be used accordingly. How can both aspects be reconciled?

The order constraint can be alleviated by narrowing the scope impure computations may occur in (please note that `_let` essentially provides a nicer IIFE syntax):

```
const _let = (...args) => ({in: f => f(...args)});

try{xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)}
catch(e) {log(e.message)} // xs is not defined

const xs = _let([1,2,3]).in(xs => {
  xs.push(4);
  //..
  xs.push(5);
  return xs;
});

xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 15
```

Now mutations are encapsulated in the inner scope and opaque to its parent. It's remotely comparable with DB transactions. It's also easer to track mutations, because the amount of effected code is smaller.

Sometimes it isn't possible to keep the impure scope limited. Coyping the reference value once is an acceptable trade-off in these circumstances:

```
const _let = (...args) => ({in: f => f(...args)});
const copy = xs => xs.concat();
const xs = [1,2,3];

xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 6

const ys = _let(copy(xs)).in(zs => {
  zs.push(4);
  //..
  zs.push(5);
  return zs;
});

xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 6
ys.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0); // 15
```

Comment: For me it is strange to see such code that doesn't always copy input, for me it is important that I can test each function in isolation from all other steps. Inside a function I consider mutations as fine, but I never mutate inputs. I never actually thought why, it was just the right way, maybe this makes sense but it would require some time to think.

Comment: In this example, the `_let` part which has `push(4)` and `push(5)`, I take it that in your opinion instead of just push there could be entire functions that could do some complex work? And you would not make a copy unless you have to? Is it because of performance? I kind of tryed something like that on a Map of Maps and it was hard to take it apart, it ended up being a big function, but I made as few copies as possible. Compared to a similar thing that used objects instead and was made with ramda, where each step was isolated, but where on each step a copy was made.

Comment: Ok so in first example we don't make a copy because we just created collection in place and nobody could access it before anyway. In second example that is not the case and we copy it. This makes perfect sense actually.

Comment: If we imagine a function that updates collection, updates would add some stuff and delete other etc, we can separate add and delete into their own functions, would you make those functions pure or impure given that they will be used only inside this function?